# How can I save a dictionary into database. [C#]

Tags: c#

**How can I save a dictionary into database? or should I use a different approach for my desired output?**

I have 2 categories.
Category - A  and
Category - B

**Category - A**
**Steps:**

- I select Category A in comboBox1
- Enter serial number from 100 and to 150.
- The serials gets generated and added into combobox2.
- ComboBox2 consists of serials: {100,101,102,103,104,105.. and so on}, and nothing else.

[image: Category - A]

**Category - B**
**Steps:**

- I select Category B in comboBox1
- Enter serial number from 200 and to 250.
- The serials gets generated and added into combobox2.
- ComboBox2 consists of serials: {200,201,202,203,204,205.. and so on}, and nothing else.

[image: Category - B]

**Selecting ComboBox1**
**IndexChangedEvent**

When I select Category - A, I only see Category A Serials in comboBox2 and nothing else.

When I select Category - B, I only see Category B Serials in comboBox2 and nothing else.

**Next Step: (Desired Result)**

- I want to store each Category A with it's serials and Category B with it's serials in a database so when I re-open the application, and select my category A, I can able to see my generated serials from Category-A in comboBox2 and when I select Category-B I can able to see my generated serials from Category-B in comboBox2 and nothing else. The problem is how can I store a dictionary into database.

**Code**

```
private void Generate_button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                comboBox2.Items.Clear();

                from = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
                to = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);

                result = to - from;

                for (int i = 0; i <= result; i++)
                {
                    string item = Convert.ToString(from + i); // Given"A" to seperate from each other
                    comboBox2.Items.Add(item);
                    vals.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(0, item)); // CatA has 0 key value
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Serial Book Generated Success", "Success");
            }

            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                comboBox2.Items.Clear();

                from = int.Parse(textBox2.Text); //50
                to = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);   // 60

                result = to - from;  // 10

                for (int i = 0; i <= result; i++)
                {

                    string item = Convert.ToString(from + i); // Given"A" to seperate from each other
                    comboBox2.Items.Add(item);
                    vals.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(1, item)); // CatA has 0 key value

                }
                MessageBox.Show("Serial Book Generated Success", "Success");
            }
        }
```

**ComboBox1 Code Index Event Changed**

```
if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                comboBox2.Items.Clear();

                foreach (var item in vals)
                {
                    if (item.Key == 0) //If Key value is 0, if it is CategoryA
                    {
                        comboBox2.Items.Add(item.Value);
                        // MessageBox.Show("Adding: " + (item.Value.ToString()));
                        comboBox2.Refresh();
                    }
                }
            }

                if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
                {    
                    comboBox2.Items.Clear();
                    foreach (var item in vals)
                    {
                        if (item.Key == 1)    //If Key value is 1, if it is CategoryB
                        {
                            comboBox2.Items.Add(item.Value);
                            comboBox2.Refresh();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Did you try to write some code that does something with a database or are you asking us to provide a full solution also with database choice, schema definition, inserts and selects queries and, why not, updates and deletes?

Comment: @Steve I had added datagridview and saved items to datagridview and retrieve them back, but that would merge both categories serials, and I would have a merged serials from Cat A and B in comboBox2, I removed the code. I am asking you to provide a code that would save the category wise data into database and retrieve them category wise back.

Comment: Create the appropriate schema in a database instance that you want to connect to. Then read up up on how to interact with the database provider (*whatever one you are working with*) and c#. Then create some class in your c# code that is responsible for saving that data and pass it your dictionary. Finally create another class or method to do the reverse. That is as good as you are going to get with this question as it is very vague. If you get stuck come back with a **specific question/problem**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saving to a database will require some work, another option (if the structure is not going to change much) is to serialize the object to json ([Using Newtonsoft's JSON.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)) and persist to disk. You could also write the serialised text to a database if you have one available and you need security and/or access and state from different machines.

You could also save the state of what values were selected at the time the application was closed so that you can give the user the exact view they were on when they next open the app.

Here is a working console application tested in .Net 4.0 (but written in VS2015).

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Populate the dictionary 
            Dictionary<int, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            myDictionary.Add(1, "one");
            myDictionary.Add(2, "two");
            myDictionary.Add(3, "three");

            // Serialise it to disk
            string jsonToWrite = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myDictionary);
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText("c:\\temp\\YourDictionary.txt"))
            {
                sw.Write(jsonToWrite);
            }

            // Deserialise it from Disk back to a Dictionary
            string jsonToRead = File.ReadAllText("c:\\temp\\YourDictionary.txt");
            Dictionary<int, string> myDictionaryReconstructed =
                       JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<int, string>>(jsonToRead);

            // Check values exist in the two dictionaries
            if (myDictionary.All(x => myDictionaryReconstructed.Any(y => x.Value == y.Value)))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Success");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting error message, json convert does not exist in current context. I'm using this namespace: using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;

Comment: Go to nuget and pull in the Newtonsoft package. https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/

Comment: Here is a guide https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-dotnet/wiki/Using-Nuget-in-Visual-Studio-2010-&-2012

Comment: all done thanks, getting this error now: Error 1 
The non-generic method 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object, System.Type, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings)' cannot be used with type arguments C:\VisualC#\Projects\BookSerial\BookSerial\Form1.cs 165 39 BookSerial
on this code `string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject<Dictionary<int, string>>(vals);`

Comment: solved it by using `string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vals);
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText("C:\\Dictionary.txt"))
            {
                sw.Write(json);
            }`

Comment: but now when I'm reading it back with this code: 

`if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 0)
                {
                    string json = File.ReadAllText("c:\\Dictionary.txt");
                    Dictionary<int, string> reload_vals =
                               JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<int, string>>(json);`

im getting this error: http://i68.tinypic.com/8yuwqr.jpg

Comment: mine is `List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> vals = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();`

is that causing the problem?

and im adding it by `vals.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(0, item));`
item is an int. My dictionary file looks like this. 
http://i67.tinypic.com/2dhwwti.jpg

Comment: Works just fine with a List of KvP - answer updated with a working sample (not sure why you are not just using a Dictionary though).

Comment: yea I changed my code from KeyValuePair to Dictionary, but I'm unable to repopulate comboBox2 with the values.

Comment: i will accept this answer for now as the solution is working but the main confusion is, should I save keyvalue pair and read with json or should I use dictionary.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120143/discussion-between-murray-foxcroft-and-patrick).